# OllyDbg - how to jump to a specific section within a (PE) Portable Executable?

Tags: ollydbg

When loading a .exe file within OllyDbg how can I step into the 'User Code' section?

Pressing 'Execute till User Code' (alt-f9) does nothing unfortunately for me.

If you need more information don't hesitate to ask

Comment: I am pretty sure You better to start from Entry point. Statically look into binary PE, find Entry Point address [AddressOfEntryPoint - usually RVA from Base]. When execute it with Olly, set breakpoint on EntryPointAddress and press Run.

Answer (score 4):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enter the address of the code you want to execute. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> (the numeric keypad <kbd>*</kbd> key, *not* the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> key).

Comment: How do I know what address translates to what section of the code within the interface? If WpMain is on address ex 'xxxxx' how can I tell what address the User Code section is?

Comment: Open the Memory Map (View->Memory or Alt+M) to get all the sections.

Comment: @BDillan, you might need to explain what you mean by "User Code".